# What is the difference between [[0 for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)] and [0 for _ in range(10)] * 10?

Tags: python, list

```
>>> CM = [[0 for _ in range(10)]] * 10
>>> CM    
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> CM[0][0] = CM[0][0] + 1
>>> CM
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I was trying to create a confusion matrix. It basically contains count of the (i, j) pairs.
I first created a list of lists, and then incremented the appropriate variable. However, it didn't work as expected. CM[i][0] got incremented for all values of i.

I found a work around.

```
>>> CM = [[0 for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
>>> CM
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> CM[0][0] = CM[0][0] + 1
>>> CM
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

But I would be grateful if someone could explain why the first method failed.

Comment: Thanks! I tried searching, but perhaps didn't use the right query.

Comment: Note that `CM = [[0]*10 for _ in range(10)]` will work here as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> CM = [[0 for _ in range(10)]] * 10
```

Is copying a reference to the same object, ten times. It is equivalent to this:

```
>>> x = [0 for _ in range(10)]
>>> CM = [x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x]
```

So manipulating one element causes side effects. Your workaround is elegant and correct.

**Note:**

This occurs since the elements of the lists are lists (which are mutable). If they were strings for example, which are immutable, it wouldn't be an issue if the same string was referenced in different lists, since they can't be manipulated. Python doesn't like to waste memory (unless explicitly told to ie. `deepcopy`), so copying lists will simply copy their references.

Comment: Thank you! This is my first question on Stack Overflow and got answered immediately! Thanks a lot!